# ActionListener for buttons in a loop not working

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, jbutton, event-listener

I have a jpanel in which i am add a variable number of buttons and then associating action listeners with each of them.
I add actionListener with the help of a loop.
but when I click the buttons nothing happens
I have seen some other answers on the topic but they don't seem to work for me. 
Please point out my mistake.

```
    jPanel4.setLayout(new GridLayout(20,2));

for(int i=1;i<=40;i++){
 JButton b1=new JButton(""+i);
jPanel4.add(new JButton(""+i));
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){genactionPerformed(evt);}
});
}


private void genactionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You clicked" +evt.getActionCommand());
    }
```

Comment: You're creating two instances of `JButton`, one on the screen and one you are adding the `ActionListener` to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add b1 to jPanel and not `new JButton(""+i))`.

```
jPanel4.add(b1);
```

Comment: if your issue is resolved please mark this answer accepted. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers